# Detecting stale blocks with ZeroMQ

Tags: block, zeromq, stale-block

I'am writing an application which receives information about new tx and blocks via ZeroMQ. There is a chance that I will receive notifs about blocks which will later on become stale blocks. Is there a way to verify whether the block has become stale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a direct way to do this via ZeroMQ. Your best bet would be to validate the ancestry for each block as you receive it.

When you receive a block, check its parent hash against blocks you have already seen. If the parent chain validates *and* you do not have another, longer child chain from the parent block already, you can accept this block.